# Javascript regexp non greedy search for quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I have following text:

`<a href="{{'Čeština' | l10n}}" ng-click="setLocale('cs_CZ')">{{field.text || 'Čeština' | l10n}}</a>`

Regexp:
`/((?!l10n))*?(['"])(.*?)\2[\s]*?\|[\s]*?l10n/g`

And I am trying to replace strings before `l10n` with modified strings. My regexp is working fine except for this situation, where it eats `'` from `setLocale` function.

Here is interactive regex tester with my expression - https://regex101.com/r/vX5tJ6/3

Question is, why is it eating the `'` from setLocale when there is no `|` after (as specified in regexp)?

Comment: Try [`((?!l10n))*?(['"])(.*?)\2(?:\)|[\s]*?\|[\s]*?l10n)`](https://regex101.com/r/vX5tJ6/4).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I am looking for two matches, each with the word `Čeština`, this regexp does not match that :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
(['"])([^'"]*)\1\s*\|\s*l10n
```

https://regex101.com/r/lV8wV7/1

It looks for anything in single or double quotes followed by `| l10n` with optional spaces.

Your regex was matching a single or double quote, followed by any characters, non-greedily, then another matching quote.  However, it was able to non-greedily match the enclosing quotes (so not just the last satisfying quote it encountered) without violating the rest of the pattern.

The main difference in the above pattern is that it won't allow enclosing quotes.

If you need to allow double quotes enclosed in single quotes or single quotes in double quotes, you can try the following:

```
(?:(')([^']*)'|(")([^"]*)")\s*\|\s*l10n
```

https://regex101.com/r/mL8gA6/1

Comment: Thanks, its almost it :) Just one more problem, with only one occurence of replacing strings it does this - https://regex101.com/r/vX5tJ6/5 which si why I had that `(?!l10n)` in my regexp

Comment: The first version seems too risky to me, allowing `'` to match to `"` and vice-versa.

Comment: @Pirozek - I'm not seeing what the issue is with a single occurrence?  Do you only want to match if the pattern occurs in **both** the href attribute and the text?

Comment: @dustmouse Yeah, sorry, the second regexp is working like a charm, thanks a lot!